# Flash to HTML5 Loss of interactivity

Tags: html, actionscript-3, html5-canvas, createjs, google-swiffy

I have Some sample fla Content which I am not able to convert into HTML5 with interactions

What I tried is

1. Google Swiffy --> Gives interactions [not full] but no sound. Issue is it works for content less than 1 MB
2. Toolkit for CreateJs --> Initially I got jsx errors but I cleared them by removing Special Characters in element names. But non of the case I got interactivity [Means I was not able to use my Mouse events or clicks
3. HTML5 Canvas in Flash Pro CC --> even here I got same above result.

Did I am missing something ??

Comment: Note that HTLM5 Canvas in Flash CC is just an upgraded version of the Toolkit for CreateJS.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't really miss anything. Flash's HTML conversions do not convert AS3 to JS (that would be nice if it did). In this case you have to write the interaction using JS.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're using [Google's online SWF-to-Swiffy converter](https://developers.google.com/swiffy/convert/upload), which has a 1MB limit. There's a better way, if you have Flash Pro CS5 or CS6 and the original FLA files. Try this:

- [download Google's swiffy generator](https://developers.google.com/swiffy/convert/flash-extension) and instal it in your Flash Pro (read instructions carefully)
- open your FLAs and find the sounds that don't play in the swiffy file - most likely they are set as streaming sound (streaming audio is not supported by Swiffy), so change them to event sound
- BUT, looped event sounds exported to Swiffy only play once (they don't loop), so if you need them, export the sound from the FLA (as .wav), and copy and paste it as  many times as necessary in a new .wav file and re-import
- All done? Now export from Flash Pro using Command -> Export as HTML5 (swiffy)

**NB:** Google's Swiffy extension for Flash Pro won't work with Creative Cloud, and **on mobiles** there'll be **NO AUDIO whatever you do** - sound only seems to work on desktop PCs, owing to [mobile restrictions on unsolicited big-file preloads](http://buildingwebapps.blogspot.it/2012/04/state-of-html5-audio-in-mobile-safari.html).